# warning: here-document in bash

Tags: bash

while executing the following code

```
list="$(Result "$VARDB" "$VAR2" - <<-EOT
SELECT d.day || '@' || t.mo 
FROM    daa a,dab b;
EOT)"
```

I get the following error:

```
warning: here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOT')
```

The code works well under bash version 3.2.25 but it triggers the error under version 4.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
list="$(Result "$VARDB" "$VAR2" - <<EOT
SELECT d.day || '@' || t.mo 
FROM    daa a,dab b;
EOT
)"
```

It's because the *here-doc* starts literally with any string. So the start is `EOT` and the end of file is found instead of `EOT`.
The shell just see `EOT)` not `EOT`